# Angular expression does'nt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I'm starting to coding in angular.js on webstorm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="store">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>
{{1 + 1}}
</body>
</html>
```

but the browser display 
`Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}
{{1 + 1}}`

what can i do?

Comment: Need more details before someone can help. What is the content of app.js, specifically module declaration. What are the errors log in browser console log?

Comment: you should use the `ng-app` attribute in either your `html` tag or `body` (or any other), not both.

Comment: i tried to use ng-app only in the Html tag and it didnt work...

Comment: What does your app.js file look like?

Answer (score -1):

You don't provide enough details to resolve the issue, but I made these four changes to your HTML to get it working, at least with respect to AngularJS:

1. Remove the 'ng-app' attribute from the **body** tag.
2. Use a CDN URL for angularjs.
3. Remove the reference to your js file.
4. Remove your store app from the 'ng-app' attribute in the **html** tag.

This modified version of your HTML runs fine using WebStorm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>
<p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>
{{1 + 1}}
</body>
</html>
```

Once you see that working, you can progressively undo the changes I made (undo 2, then 3 then 4, but retain change 1), and retest to identify the problem.

More details are needed to determine the root cause, but the most likely issues are:

1. Your angularjs file can't be found.
2. Your "app.js" file can't be found.
3. Some problem(s) with your code in app.js.

But since you are using WebStorm, it may be able to identify your precise problem. Run Code=>Inspect Code on your project, then review the output. It will identify very basic problems, such as failing to locate your script files.

Comment: My answer was posted in July 2014, and relates to AngularJS which was superseded three months later, yet someone down-votes it today, over four years later?! Creepy.